# Perform aggregate operation (sum) across an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following object collection.

```
const expenses = [
{id:1, type:"books", title:"print book purchase", amount:50},
{id:2, type:"books", title:"ebook purchase", amount:10},
{id:3, type:"grocery", title:"vegetables", amount:5},
{id:4, type:"grocery", title:"milk", amount:5},
{id:5, type:"grocery", title:"eggs", amount:10}
]

 const newArr = expenses.map((item)=>{
                     return item.type
        })
        
        this.querySet = new Set(newArr)

//Loop twice 
//Outer loop for each 'type'
//Inner loop for each object in the expenses array


        this.querySet.forEach(set_iter=>{

                this.records.forEach(rec_iter=>{
                   
                    if(set_iter === rec_iter.Type__c)
                    {
                       //Not sure how to perform a sum and produce the output below
                        
                    }
                })

        })
```

I am not able to wrap my head around as to how to perform a sum of expense for each type across the objects in the `expenses` array and produce an array of objects with a property containing the total.

My expected output is something like below

Can anyone guide me as to how that can be done ?

```
Expected Output 

[
{type:'books',total:60},
{type:'grocery',total:20}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object (or Map) indexed by the `type` of the items. When iterating over the array, use the object's `type` to add the amount to the appropriate property. Once everything is summed up, you can turn it back into an array of objects by iterating over the entries.

```js
const expenses = [
  {id:1, type:"books", title:"print book purchase", amount:50},
  {id:2, type:"books", title:"ebook purchase", amount:10},
  {id:3, type:"grocery", title:"vegetables", amount:5},
  {id:4, type:"grocery", title:"milk", amount:5},
  {id:5, type:"grocery", title:"eggs", amount:10}
];

const sums = {};
for (const { type, amount } of expenses) {
  sums[type] = (sums[type] || 0) + amount;
}
const output = Object.entries(sums).map(([type, total]) => ({ type, total }));
console.log(output);
```